# Why can't set complete file path on JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, filepath

I'm building a program that scans through directories. I want the current directory scanned be displayed on the JLabel. I can't understand why is it that the complete file directory is not displayed. Ex. - 'C:\Program Files(86)' is displayed instead of 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin\javaw.exe'. But using System.out.println(), the complete directory is displayed. Please help me on this? Thanks....

Please see my code below:

[EDITED]

```
    public void search(){
    ....
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        String path = file.getPath().replace('\\', '/');

        changeLabelText(path); //set JLabel text
        System.out.println(path); //shows complete filepath
    ....
    }

    public void changeLabelText(String path){
        this.lblPath.setText(path);
    }

    //start scan 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == btnStart) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                search();
            }
        }).start();
        }
     }

     //constructor
     public AuditFiles() {
     ...    
         btnStart = new JButton("Scan");
         btnStart.addActionListener(this);

         lblPath = new JLabel("Current Directory: ");
         lblPath.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 20));
     ...
     }
```

Comment: The case here is different. JLabel is updating.

Comment: Either the above code is running inside the EDT, and the question is a duplicate of the one I linked to, or it's not running in the EDT, and it's incorrect because you access a Swing component from a thread that is not the EDT. In any of the situation, the solution is to correctly use a SwingWorker.

Comment: It's possible that the label doesn't have space to display the label, but your are violating the single thread rule of Swing, which isn't going to help...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: this would cause the label to display ellipsis, wouldn't it? (it displays ellipsis in my tests).

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I also tried setting the size of the frame or the label itself to fit for long texts. Apologies, I'm really new working with GUIs or threading/EDT.

Comment: Could you show more of your program? Ideally a dedicated sample program to show just this specific issue; I'm keen to see how you're setting up the frame, how you're creating the label and how you're laying components out.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  See also this [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

Comment: @JBNizet It depends on who the label is laid out.  If they are using a `null` layout, it may not...

Comment: @JBNizet I also found (while using `GridBagLayout`), it was possible for the label to exceed the width of the frame, but not display "..."